# All the strings lexicographically greater than X and smaller than Y

Tags: python, string, lexicographic

How can I find all the strings in "python" which are lexicographically greater than X and smaller than Y? X and Y are of same length.

Example:

```
X = "ab" and Y = "ad"
```

So the answer will be:

```
"ab", "ac" and "ad"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: In which language? English? French? German?

Comment: @PeterWood: Edited the problem statement. Its in Python

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I meant which language does the ordering come from? Are we using just ASCII strings, or unicode?

Comment: Bear in mind that if `X='af'; Y='cg'` then 'b[a..z]' will fit the requirements - this can grow enormous - also are you looking for case independence i.e. 'A'..'b' includes 'B'..'Z', 'a'.

Comment: @SteveBarnes yes the strings only contains lowercase letters.

Comment: There are an infinite number of them, so you can't list them all. E.g. In your example, 'aba', 'abaa', 'abaaa' etc.

Comment: @oefe: The number can't be Infinite because as mentioned both the strings are of same length.

Comment: You only said both X and Y are the same length, not about the results. You might want to edit your question to include the constraints which you clarified in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode you can start from:

```
lower=...
upper=...
str = next(lower)
while before(str, upper) :
    print(str)
    str = next(str)
```

The `next` function:

```
def next (str) :
    if str[-1] != 'z' :
        return str[:-1] + chr(ord(str[-1]) + 1) # increment last char
    else:
        return next( str[0:-1] ) + 'a' # reset last char and increment previous
```

The `before` function:

```
def before (a, b) :
   for i in 0.. (len(a)-1) :
       if a[i] < b[i] :
           return True
   return False
```

Comment: I guess your `next` function is wrong. I would do `return str[:-1] + chr(ord(str[-1]) + 1)` in the first case and `return next(str[:-1]) + 'a'` in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is:

```
X = 'ab'
Y = 'ad'

x = [chr(x) + chr(y) for x in range(ord(X[0]),ord(Y[0])+1) for y in range(ord(X[1]),ord(Y[1])+1)]

print(x)
```

Comment: Very clever solution. It's a pity it only works with strings of length 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can view this as converting from base 26 to get a range of integers, then convert those integers back into base 26. You can either roll your own for that, or `pip install python-baseconv`, eg:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from baseconv import BaseConverter

def lex_range(start, end):
    if len(start) != len(end):
        raise ValueError('inputs must be same length')
    B26 = BaseConverter(ascii_lowercase)
    # use `xrange` in Py 2.x
    for n in range(int(B26.decode(start)), int(B26.decode(end)) + 1):
        yield B26.encode(n).rjust(len(start), 'a')

for result in lex_range('ab', 'ad'):
    print(result)
```

**Note** - the above will work as long as they're lexicographically `start <= end` - they don't need to be the same length, so `lex_range('a', 'zz')` would still produce the desired output - hence the explicit `len` check.

Output:

```
# ab
# ac
# ad
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's write a function to find the lexicographically next string after the current (with the same length, and only using the characters a-z), I.e., to increment it. In most cases, that's easy – just increment the last character. However, if the last character is the highest possible character in our set (z), we start over with a, and increment the remaining string.

```
def next(s):
    front = s[:-1]
    last = s[-1]
    if last < 'z':
        return front + chr(ord(last) + 1)
    else:
        return next(front) + 'a'
```

Now we can use that to print all strings in the given range:

```
def print_between(start, end):
    s = start
    while s <= end:
        print (s)
        s = next(s)
```

Example:

```
print_between('ab', 'ad')
```